# How can I initial a controller by class name，while this controller is in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Is there any way to initial a storyboard controller without knowing storyboard name?

What I can get: controller's class name and controller's storyboard id.

It's worth noting that I don't need to know the name of the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The view controller (scene) in the storyboard must have an *identifier*. This is not a class; it’s a string. Now you can call `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` using that string.

Comment: It seems that I have not expressed clearly. I have updated the question. Can you please look at it again?

Comment: That doesn’t change my answer. The class name would be pointless anyway because a storyboard can have many instances of a view controller class. The identifier is how you identify!

Comment: ‘instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)‘ must get storyboard first，which means should know storyboard's name, that's not my original intention.

Comment: I don’t care what your intention is. You can’t get something out of a storyboard without a reference to that storyboard. If you don’t like that then don’t use storyboards!

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is NO**.

You cannot instantiate any ViewController without knowing the storyboard name. You can do so if you create an .xib file of that ViewController and use it like this :

```
    let vc = YourControllerName(nibName: "fileName", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Hope it helps !